# navigation with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so i am a begginer and i really need help
so i wrote this function down here;
the objective was to take as parameters an element name , a div tag selector and a php file address,

> ```
> function navigation($nav,$container,$link)
> { 
>
>
>  $($nav).click(function(){
>     $($container).slideUp(500,function(e){
>     $(this).append("<span>");
>     $(this).load($link);
>     });
>   });
>   {
>   $($container).ajaxComplete(function(){
>   $(this).slideDown(500);
> });
>   }
>   {
>     $($container).slideUp(500);
>   }
> }
> ```

**the usage is simple**

```
    navigation("#home",".content","home.php");
   navigation("#about",".content","about.php");
    navigation("#store",".content","right.php");
```

the html is just a few `<div>` one with `class=".content"` tag and `<a>` links called `#home #about #store` the pages in php are just plain html inside them;

---

now the problem is when i click the link it works but i can find how to make he active link unclickable after it becomes active
and i was about to do a sublist with the same function trying to load a little div under the navigation links that contain links but i cant find how to do 
any one of pro's have any idea ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help but it's going to be quite a rewrite.

Firstly, give all your navigation items a class.  Inside the nav items (I don't know if they're `div`, `li` elements or whatever, put an `<a>` tag with the src set to the page you want the navigation to load.  When done it might look something like below:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="nav">
        <a src="home.php">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav">
        <a src="about.php">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav">
        <a src="right.php">RIGHT</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then use jQuery's onload functionality to bind the click event onload, rather than calling your navigation function 3 times.  You grab the src from the child `<a>` tag of the `li` clicked.

```
$(function()
{
    $('.nav').click(function()
    {
        if($(this).hasClass('active'))
        {
            return false;
        }
        $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $('.content').slideUp(500).load($(this).children('a').attr('src'), 
            null,
            function(){$(this).slideDown(500);}
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Note the `return false;` is important to prevent the default action of the link (i.e. sending the user to the other page).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'child'
javascript console show's me this error 
are you sure u didnt forgot something ??

Comment: Gah, it's `children` not child.  Was distracted by UFC on TV. Updating now.

Comment: @Qchmqs I believe the added lines should do the slideup/down correctly.  `load` accepts 3 params.  The second is data to send back to the script you're loading, the 3rd is a function to execute on completion of the load.  We call the slideup immediately before the chained load then call the slidedown in the complete function of the load.  I can't guarantee the context of `this` will be correct in the load complete function.  You may have to change `this` to `'.content'`

Comment: @Qchmqs Apologies if I was abrupt with my early comments.  It's late here and tone is impossible to convey via print.

Comment: there still only one question .
how i can make the `slideDown()` goes after the loading was finished not in the same time ??
and how i can do slideUp before that 
i know i am asking too mush but ii am a beginner(i have a lot of theory studies but this is my first job in real life)

Answer (score 0):

There's several approaches to making a link unclickable. One would be to let the click-event unbind itself:

```
$('nav')click(function(){
//Your code goes here
$(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Another would be to manipulate its CSS to hide the element (set `display` to `none`).

As for the second part of your question, i don't really get what you want to do. If you want to have a popout under the link, that activates on hover, you can see here how that could be achieved by using an `<ul>` and its `:hover` event

http://jsfiddle.net/D3AP2/